# Performing Project_management in batch using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, error-999999

```
import arcpy
import os

fc = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk('C:/Wiley/P1/gis/OSM.gdb')

outdir = "C:/Wiley/P1/gis/HK80.gdb/osm"

for root, dirs, datasets in walk:
    for ds in datasets:
        fc.append(os.path.join(root, ds))

if fc:
    output = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(ds) + "_project")    
    hkfc = "C:\Wiley\P1\gis\HK80.gdb\Building_merge_dissolved"
    # Describe the feature class and get its spatial reference
    desc = arcpy.Describe(hkfc)
    spatialRef = desc.spatialReference

    out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('spatialRef.name')

    arcpy.Project_management(fc, output, out_coordinate_system)
```

I am sure with a trained eye you guys know what to do.
It  came back to me with the following error:

*Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 21, in 
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 962, in **init**
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.*

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to loop through all the feature classes you're collecting, so it should be:

```
# we only need to do this once
hkfc = "C:\Wiley\P1\gis\HK80.gdb\Building_merge_dissolved"
desc = arcpy.Describe(hkfc)
spatialRef = desc.spatialReference

for input in fc:
    output = os.path.join(outdir, os.path.basename(input) + "_project")    
    arcpy.Project_management(input, output, spatialRef)
```

The way you're using `walk` is a little awkward but should be functional.

Comment: Thx for your answer!! I will try it tmr!

Comment: Alright I understand now. Always use the variables inside the for function.